# Edimax (7392:c711) Wifi Adapter - Driver needed for Linux Mint 18

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, wifi, drivers, usb

I'm having problems to find drivers for my `Devolo Wifi Stick ac`, which is displayed as `Edimax Technology Co., Ltd` (Vendor-ID: `7392`) and the Device-ID `c711`. When I plugin the Stick, it gets displayed as `Mediatek` in my syslog.

I've searched a lot of forums, tested a lot of drivers and even tried to use Windows 10-Drivers with ndiswrapper. I used this Stick before on Windows 10 and it was working w/o a problem, except when I tried to change the wireless-network -> I had to restart my Notebook. This looked to me like a power-problem, but I'm not sure about it. Currently my notebook is connected with the built-in wireless-card (Broadcom), which is to slow for my needs.

The first thing I tried after I didn't found any Linux-Driver for this Stick, was to use ndiswrapper/ndisgtk and getting all needed files from my Windows 10 Installation. The Device-Manager listed these files:

- **Strong Name of Drivernode:** `oem56.inf`
- **INF-Part:** `OS61_RTWLANSE.ndi`
- **INF-Name:** `oem56.inf`
- **Included INF-Files:** `netvwifibus.inf`
- **Service:** `netr28ux`
- **Driver-Files:** `FW_7662.bin`, `netr28ux.sys`, `Patch_7662.bin`, `viwifibus.sys`, `RaCoInst.dat`, `RaCoInstx.dll`

After some research I found out that MediaTek acquired RaLink and this way it explained to me why I found an `RT2870.inf` inside of a Driver-Folder I downloaded with some difficulties from a russian site. The files included in this folder are (`USB_wifi_ WinXP_Vista_7x64.zip`):

- `FW_7662.bin`
- `netr28ux.cat`
- `netr28ux.inf`
- `netr28ux.sys`
- `Patch_7662.bin`
- `RaCoInst.dat`
- `RaCoInstx.dll`
- `rt2870.cat`
- `RT2870.inf`
- `RT2870.sys`

So maybe this stick is using a RaLink Chipset? I don't know, because there is no more information about it. Even the manual or vendor-homepage didn't gave me any clue what chipset is used. So, if I'm using the driver above with ndiswrapper, I'm getting the following errors in my syslog:

```
usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=7392, idProduct=c711
usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 3-2: Product: WiFi
usb 3-2: Manufacturer: MediaTek
usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 1.0
usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: ntoskrnl.exe:'ExEventObjectType'
ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: ntoskrnl.exe:'MmGetSystemRoutineAddress'
ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: ntoskrnl.exe:'IoWMIWriteEvent'
ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: ntoskrnl.exe:'RtlStringFromGUID'
ndiswrapper (import:232): unknown symbol: ntoskrnl.exe:'__chkstk'
ndiswrapper (load_sys_files:200): couldn't prepare driver 'rt2870'
ndiswrapper (load_wrap_driver:103): couldn't load driver rt2870; check system log for messages from 'loadndisdriver'
loadndisdriver: loadndisdriver: load_driver(364): couldn't load driver rt2870
```

I couldn't find this driver in the MediaTek-Download-Section, the files were modified on 12th May 2016 and this driver looks the most promising to me, because it shows less errors for ndiswrapper compared to my Windows 10 driver and also less errors compared to `netr28ux.inf`, which is also part of the archive, I got from the said russian site. I also found a thread with some Windows XP driver which also didn't worked for me. I hope someone can help me with, I'm out of ideas.

**Additional information comes here**

Afaik this Wifi-Stick is limited to 5 GHz, supports speeds up to 433 MBit/s, it looks like [this](http://computertaal.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/USB-stick_1.jpg) and has a blue led which should light up when powered/connected. I can only get information about this stick via log-files or `lsusb`.

**OS:** Linux Mint 18 Sarah 64bit (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)
**Kernel:** 4.4.0-38-generic

**lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:58e6 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1a1d:0002 Veho 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 7392:c711 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57781 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
04:00.0 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller (rev 30)
04:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller (rev 30)
04:00.3 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller (rev 30)
04:00.4 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. xD Host Controller (rev 30)
```

**iwconfig**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
enp1s0    no wireless extensions.
wlp2s0b1  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"*********"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 34:31:C4:06:07:78   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:11716  Invalid misc:3258   Missed beacon:0
```

`wlp2s0b1` IS NOT the Wifi-Stick and instead the built-in wifi-card. (PCI)

Copied from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834672/edimax-7392c711-wifi-adapter-driver-needed-for-ubuntu-16-04-lts), because the question got rejected due to not being "an official flavour of Ubuntu". (I'm the author of both questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So maybe this stick is using a RaLink Chipset?

According to [wikidevi](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Elecom_WDC-433SU2M) the probable driver is the `mt7610u_sta` ( use the ID: `7392:a711` to get the necessary information ) , the driver can be installed as [follows](https://github.com/Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916):

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
mkdir ~/src
cd ~/src
git clone https://github.com/Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.git
make
make install
cp RT2870STA.dat  /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat
reboot
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Okay, I tried to get more information on my own, because your suggestion didn't worked. Now I came back to the hprath-blog which also doesn't work for me.(his driver) I'm getting some errors during make and I'm not sure if this could be the problem. ([log](http://paste.ee/p/HSzY8) & [full log](http://paste.ee/p/FnWoP)) I also unplugged the stick and rebooted. Do you have any more advice? The official MediaTek driver also doesn't work but like you can read on the blog I linked to, it seems their driver doesn't works well for a lot of ppl.

Comment: Ok it looks like I got it partially working now. I added my vendor-id (c711) to `rtusb_dev_id.c`, changed the WifiMode in `/etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat` to 13 used `sudo modprobe mt7610u_sta`, then `sudo ifconfig ra0 up` (led lights up) and then `sudo service network-manager restart`. Now only one network gets displayed and it isn't mine. Any idea what I should change?

Comment: take a look here http://www.cyberciti.biz/files/README_STA.txt

Comment: This Readme should be self-explanatory and I'm finally having full speed with this stick. I think I can find out the rest on my own. Just for anyone from Germany I'm posting the file and it should look like [this](http://paste.ee/p/YxrxG) if I'm right. Issue is solved for me and you pointed me into the right direction, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Pandora: Thanks for the configuration file. Inhabitants of other countries merely need to change the values of the entries starting with `Country` and `ChannelGeography` (lines 12–15) to whatever applies to them.